# rtl for persian navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

i have a  e-ccommerce app is ltr and english languge...i want translate to persian and rtl

Comment: Have you added: `android:supportsRtl="true"` to AndoridManifest.xml ? Which `NavigationDrawer` are you talking about? Any links to source or github library?

Comment: thank you,i have a  e-ccommerce app is ltr and english languge...i want translate to persian and rtl

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to `AndoridManifest.xml` and then, you'll need to create another `Strings.xml` in order to translate the app to Persian or any languages.

Create `values-fa` in `/res` directory of your project and then, copy-paste the `Strings.xml` into the `values-fa` directory.

Then you'll be able to translate those words in Persian in order to show in the app later. However, Android Studio has `Edit Translation` for these situations which if you did like I mentioned, click on `Open Editor`:

[image]

Then translating the strings will be pretty easy.

**Read:** https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages